# Search in list of expandoObject

Tags: c#, linq, list, search, dynamic

Suppose I have a `List` of dynamic objects like:

```
var records = [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "sai",
    "Age": "4",
    "About": "12.02.1991"
  },
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "hjfh",
    "Age": "2",
    "About": "12.02.1991"
  },
{
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "hello name",
    "Age": "6",
    "About": "hi"
  },
{
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": 1,
    "Age": "9",
    "About": "hello world"
  }
]

string searchString = "Hello";
```

I tried something like:

```
foreach (var item in records )
{

    foreach (var field in item)
    {
        if (field.Value != null && field.Value.ToString().IndexOf(query.SearchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) 
        {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the count of records which has `searchString` at any field in the record. but can I write this using a `LINQ` query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is your code, converted to a linq expression:
You have access to the field and the object in the select statement.

```
    records.Cast<ExpandoObject>().SelectMany(x => x, (obj, field) => new { obj, field })
        .Where(x => x.field.Value != null && x.field.Value.ToString().IndexOf(SearchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        .Select(x => x.field.Key);
```

To count the number of objects that have at least one field that contains the searchstring:

```
    records.Cast<ExpandoObject>()
        .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.Value != null && y.Value.ToString().IndexOf(SearchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        .Count();
```

Comment: thanks @codemonkey

It is returning the no of fields containing search string, but i want no of records which have search string at any place, if the search string exist at 2 or more places in single record, it should count for once only

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:
logic:

```
var qry = records.Where(x=>x.Field.Contains(searchedstring)).Count();
```

real example:

```
var qry = records.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("sai")).Count();
```

Comment: It'll most likely be a contains rather than `==`.  Considering the fact that it is a search.

Comment: Thanks for yoour answer @Maciej Los
I want to search in each field in each record

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest code.

```
int count = records.Count(x => x.Name.StartsWith("hello") || x.About.StartsWith("hello"));
```